# OCaml lwt utop infix bind operator >>= is missing

Tags: ocaml, lwt

I call `require "lwt.simple-top" ;;` on utop and try a simple example but it is not able to find the operator `>>=`.

[image]

Comment: You can get it if you `open Lwt` first.

Comment: Or `open Lwt.Infix` if you only want to pull in operators.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `#require` is a toplevel directive, that link the library code into the toplevel. It doesn't open any modules. So in order to get the infix operators `>>=` and `>|=`, you need to open `Lwt.Infix` or `Lwt` modules, the latter will also bring all definitions from `Lwt` module, that may be considered as a namespac pollution.